# Tying Backbone Model and Collection to source graphs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking to use Backbone in conjunction with a persistent in-memory data store on Node.  I want to be able to use Backbone to access this store and reflect changes.

The data might look something like this:

```
var data =
[
    {
        baz: 'baz'
    }
]
```

What I then want to be able to do is something like this:

```
var dataCollection = new Backbone.Collection(data);
dataCollection.first().set('baz', 'new value');

data[0].baz //==> 'new value'
```

Now what's a bit more interesting is that if I do this:

```
dataCollection.add({ baz: 'a whole new baz' });

data //==>

[
    {
        baz: 'baz'
    },
    {
        baz: 'a whole new baz'
    }
]
```

Basically I want to bootstrap a Backbone model/collection with a native object/array and have any changes to the Backbone object reflected on the counterpart.

1. Is there a way to do this with native Backbone?
2. Is there anything fundamentally flawed with this idea or Backbone
   functionality that will break for whatever reason?
3. Are there any libraries that will do this that already exist?

Comment: Backbone will not change the value of your original data variable, if that's what you're asking. Unless you manually change the value of data: `data = myModel.toJSON();`.

Comment: Are you running Backbone on server side?

Comment: @HighCat Yes, I'm running it on Node.

Comment: @idbehold I understand that it doesn't.  The point was that I *want* it to, so I'm looking for recommended approaches to make that happen or if there's some reason no one does this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if backbone will run on node.  I've no experience on the subject.

As for actually reflecting changes on the backbone model/collection with the datastore, you can just listen to model/collection change events (provided it will even run).

```
this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.updateDataStore);

updateDataStore: function(model) {
   //access model.changed to reflect just the changed attributes to your datastore
}
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed

It sounds like a simple eventing system will give you all the leverage you need to do this nicely without backbone.

If you want a model.save to persist the changes to your in-memory datastore, you can just override `Backbone.sync` to not send an XHR, but just change your datastore.  The neat thing here is if you implement it for all the different http actions, you should be able to fetch as well.

Now all you'd need is an event on the model, having it watch `change` on itself, which then calls this.save:
`this.listenTo(this,'change',this.save);`.

Let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: Backbone definitely runs on Node.  Also, perhaps my question was unclear, the point was to just use a native Backbone object (or to modify the base prototypes as in creating a Backbone library to do it) as opposed to hard-wiring it manually via events, which is naturally very easy to do.